# Conformal mapping of the unit disc that is the identity at the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I am looking for a conformal mapping from the unit disc to itself $F:D\to D$ characterized by

- it sends a point $a\in D$ to the origin;
- it is the identity in $\partial D$.

I am aware of the exsitance of the Möbius transformations (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249992/conformal-mappings-from-the-unit-disc-to-itself)), that send $\partial D$ to $\partial D$: $F(\partial D)=\partial D$. However, the property I am looking for is pointwise along the boundary: $F(z)=z$ for all $z\in\partial D$.

The question arises from a physics context. I want to find a mapping that sends the potential lines of a point charge at $a\in D$ to the potential lines of a point charge at the origin, provided that the potential vanishes in $\partial D$.

Comment: I don't think that can be done: If $F$ is such a function, then $g(z):=F(z)-z$ is zero on $\partial D$, and by the maximum principle, then $g=0$ in $D$.

Comment: @Jose27 thanks, but how would you apply the maximum principle for such function? Are conformal mappings harmonic?

Comment: @Víctor If $f = u+iv$ is holomorphic, then $u,v$ are harmonic.

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray I see, thank you very much.

Comment: Another way to think about it is *every* univalent map from $D\longrightarrow D$ is Möbius transformation (of a particular form) and if a Möbius transformation has 3 distinct fixed points on the extended complex plane, then it must be the identity.